# OSX Safari push messages

Tags: macos, safari, apple-push-notifications

I've a problem signing the manifest.json file on my Java server. I create the various file for the pushpackage, put all those files in the manifest as described in [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html).

Then I try to create the "Signature" file using this method

```
    private static byte[] getSignatureFile(byte[] store, byte[] dataToSign) throws KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, UnrecoverableKeyException,
        SignatureException {
    if (store == null) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not find store file (.p12)");
        return null;
    }
    // First load the keystore object by providing the p12 file path
    KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    // replace testPass with the p12 password/pin
    clientStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(store), STOREPASS.toCharArray());

    Enumeration<String> aliases = clientStore.aliases();
    String aliaz = "";
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        aliaz = aliases.nextElement();
        if (clientStore.isKeyEntry(aliaz)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) clientStore.getCertificate(aliaz);

    // compute signature:
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha1WithRSA");
    signature.initSign((PrivateKey) clientStore.getKey(aliaz, STOREPASS.toCharArray()));
    signature.update(dataToSign);
    byte[] signedData = signature.sign();

    // load X500Name
    X500Name xName = X500Name.asX500Name(c.getSubjectX500Principal());
    // load serial number
    BigInteger serial = c.getSerialNumber();
    // laod digest algorithm
    AlgorithmId digestAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA_oid);
    // load signing algorithm
    AlgorithmId signAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSAEncryption_oid);

    // Create SignerInfo:
    SignerInfo sInfo = new SignerInfo(xName, serial, digestAlgorithmId, signAlgorithmId, signedData);
    // Create ContentInfo:
    ContentInfo cInfo = new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DIGESTED_DATA_OID, new DerValue(DerValue.tag_OctetString,
            dataToSign));
    // Create PKCS7 Signed data
    PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new AlgorithmId[] { digestAlgorithmId }, cInfo,
            new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] { c }, new SignerInfo[] { sInfo });
    // Write PKCS7 to bYteArray
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new DerOutputStream();
    p7.encodeSignedData(bOut);
    return bOut.toByteArray();

}
```

The "store" file contains the certificate and the private key as .p12 file.
The "dataToSign" contains the manifest.json

It is running without errors and creates me the signature file that I put then in the Zip. Everything seems to be fine, but I guess it is not creating a valid PCS7#detached signature because when I access it, it returns immediately "access denied" and in the log it says (this comes with the log rest call)

"Signature verification of push package failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I finally found the error and have it working. I exchanged this method above to a method based on BC. The complete explanation u'll find [here](http://hons82.blogspot.it/2014/02/osx-safari-push-notifications.html)